# FatJar Temp Directory

Tags: java, jar, native, executable-jar, onejar

I have native dll(C++) in my project. I'm using Eclipse FatJar Plugin to create FatJar. My native dll is dependent to other native dlls like "libopencv_core247". I know that FatJar is creating temp folder load dependent libraries from this folder. If I can find I will set the Java library path as this folder.

I can load my library and I'm getting Can not find dependent libraries error.

Comment: You have to include all c++ depended libs into your c++-lib. This lib must be in your project-ressource folder and java build path. Then it should work.

Comment: You might also have to write code to extract the dlls to a certain location as well.